# Point Cloud Library: How to use pcl::addCoordinateSystem(double scale, const Eigen::Affine3f & t, int viewport = 0))

Tags: c++, transformation, eigen, coordinate-systems, point-cloud-library

I cannot understand how to set the transformation t in the function:

`pcl::addCoordinateSystem(double scale, const Eigen::Affine3f & t, int viewport = 0))`

So the question is: how can I define an `Eigen::Affine3f`?

I have the rotation matrix and the translation vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having known the rotation and translation matrix, one can combine them to Affine3f.

```
Eigen::Affine3f tt;
tt = Eigen::Translation3f(100.,300.,0.) * Eigen::AngleAxis<float>(theta,axis);
```

Note that `Eigen::Translation3f` and `Eigen::AngleAxis3f` are not matrices here but of the abstract type Transform.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the rotation and translation in separate objects you can either do:

```
Affine3f t;
t.linear() = ...;
t.translation() = ...;
```

or:

```
t.fromPositionRotationScale(pos, rot, Vector3f::Ones());
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I was blocked because of the kdevelop parser and auto completition that didn't gave me Affine3f names and object methods but only yellow warnings :( But when I compile and run, everythings is ok!

Comment: With this, the translation works fine but not rotation

Comment: What do you mean by the rotation does not work? The method `fromPositionRotationScale` build a transformation `T` transforming points from the local space (i.e., the translated/rotated one) to the world space (i.e., the space within the position and orientation are defined).